# Avoid splatter when buffing?

Tags: polishing

I have a problem when I am buffing. Even when I rub in the buffing compound into the pad, I still tend to get splatter where tiny droplets of the compound and flung around the shop, contaminating things nearby. Any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ideas:

1. Relocate the buffer so that it's in an area away from things you don't want to contaminate.
2. Enclose the buffer in some sort of box that contains the splatter.

There is really nothing more you can do, that's the nature of these things.  You apply a compound to a rapidly spinning pad and some of it is going to get flung off.